# ESLint: Failed to load config "next/core-web-vitals" to extend from

Tags: next.js, eslint

[image]

I keep getting this error while trying to build my next.js project. The only way I found online to maybe bypass it is to ignore the eslintrc.json file. Any suggestions? Also, the file exists.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Error: Failed to load config "next" to extend from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480558/error-failed-to-load-config-next-to-extend-from)? Try installing `eslint-config-next`.

Comment: On my end the problem came from the fact that I run next@12 but npx next lint installed eslint-config-next@13

Answer (score 36):

make sure both eslint and eslint-config-next are installed

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me because I somehow ended up with an extra .eslintrc.json file outside of my Next project directory which was getting picked up by my IDE (WebStorm)

For example:

```
parent-folder
    .eslintrc.json <-- Delete this
    next-folder
        pages
        package.json
        .eslintrc.json <-- This one is correct
        tsconfig.json
        README.md
```

Comment: Note: it is possible to use ESLint and Next in a monorepo. You just need to specify the `rootDir` in the `settings` field of your ESLint config. Read the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#custom-settings)>

Comment: You saved me bro ! when i checked my parent folder there was a .eslint file. as this is a hidden file i need cntrl+h in file explorer to find it

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem and what caused it was some forced audit fixes that changed eslint-config-next to "^0.2.4".  Once I changed it back to 11.1.2 the problem was fixed.